# Linker error compiling D template

Tags: d

This is part of interpreter for a simple language. The language also includes strings, lists, functions, etc and the corresponding functions evalString, evalList, etc. functions in the Evaluator. Only the Number subclass and evalNumber function are shown.

The `Evaluator.evaluate` function calls `Expr.eval`, and each `Expr` subclass calls the correct `Evaluator` function (`evalNumber`, `evalString`, `evalList`, etc.) to evaluate the expression.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

abstract class Expr {
    Out eval(Out)(Evaluator!Out evaluator);
}

class Number: Expr {
    double num;
    this(double _num) { num = _num; }

    override Out eval(Out)(Evaluator!Out evaluator) {
        return evaluator.evalNumber(this);
    }
}

class Evaluator(Out) {
    Out evaluate(Expr expr) {
        return expr.eval(this);          // ### Error is here ### 
    }   

    abstract Out evalNumber(Number number);
}   

class ExprPrinter: Evaluator!string {
    override string evalNumber(Number num) {
        return format("%s", num.num);
    }   
}   

void main() {
    Number n = new Number(5);
    auto printer = new ExprPrinter();

    writefln("Number: %s", printer.evaluate(n));
}
```

When I try to build it, I get

```
example.o: In function `_D7example__T9EvaluatorTAyaZQp8evaluateMFCQBo4ExprZQBb':
/home/neniu/projects/duover/source/example.d:19: undefined reference to `_D7example4Expr__T4evalTAyaZQkMFCQBf__T9EvaluatorTQBaZQpZQBh'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

If I read the mangle correctly, the compiler is saying that the `expr.eval` on line 19 (marked in the code) is referring to a function which is not defined, but (in this case) the `Number.eval` function is supposed to be that function.

I have tried changing line 19 to include the Out specialisation

```
return expr.eval!Out(this);
```

but that made no difference at all.

What am I missing here? How can I get the `expr.eval(this)` call to resolve to `Number.eval`?

This is with DMD 2.081.1.

Thank you.

*&When I try to build it, I get

```
example.o: In function `_D7example__T9EvaluatorTAyaZQp8evaluateMFCQBo4ExprZQBb':
/home/neniu/projects/duover/source/example.d:19: undefined reference to `_D7example4Expr__T4evalTAyaZQkMFCQBf__T9EvaluatorTQBaZQpZQBh'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

If I read the mangle correctly, the compiler is saying that the expr.eval on line 19 (marked in the code) is referring to a function which is not defined, but (in this case) the Number.eval function is supposed to be that function.

I have tried changing line 19 to include the Out specialisation

return expr.eval!Out(this);

but that made no difference at all.

What am I missing here? How can I get the expr.expr(this) call to resolve to Number.eval?

This is with DMD 2.081.1.

Thank you.

*** Edit ***

I tried making `Expr.eval` abstract (with and without the `abstract` qualifier to the class itself, since that is the function that each subclass has to override:

```
abstract class Expr {
    abstract Out eval(Out)(Evaluator!Out evaluator);
}
```

but now the compiler complains

```
example.d(5): Error: function `example.Expr.eval!string.eval` final functions cannot be abstract
example.d(28): Error: template instance `example.Expr.eval!string` error instantiating
example.d(35):        instantiated from here: Evaluator!string
```

I don't want `Expr.eval` to be final. I've done nothing to make `Expr.eval` final. I don't see why this makes `Expr.eval` final. How do I make `Expr.eval` not final so I can make it abstract so I can -- no, have to -- override it?

Wouldn't declaring something as `abstract` ("You have to override this function") be exactly the opposite of declaring it `final` ("You can not override this function")?

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't declaring something as abstract ("You have to override this function") be exactly the opposite of declaring it final ("You can not override this function")?

Yup. But templated functions are always final. IMO, there should be an error message on `override Out eval(Out)(Evaluator!Out evaluator) {`, but apparently the compiler chooses to stay silent. You'll need to either make `eval` not be a template, or move it such that it's not a member function.

What you're doing is essentially multiple dispatch, which is implemented as a library in [OpenMethods](https://code.dlang.org/packages/openmethods). Knowing only the code you've shown, it's hard to tell if this is exactly what you need.

Comment: That would explain why `eval.expr` is undefined. It is not defined because it is `abstract`, and can't be redefined because it is `final` (because it is a template). I agree that a squawk from the compiler would be nice.

The Out return type is a parameter because some Evaluators/stages (eg. macro expansion, constant folding) emit `Expr`s for the next stage, and some (pretty printers, and translators to other languages) emit strings.

The iteration is simple enough that I can clone it in separate Changer and Translator base classes, and derived each stage from them.

Comment: Ooo. That OpenMethods looks like it might be exactly what I was after. I did have Clojure protocols and multiple dispatch in mind, but wasn't sure how to express it. I do need to explore that further but it looks like just the ticket so far Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that `Expr.eval` needs to know about the `Out` parameter type is because I can't figure out a way to get `Evaluator.evaluate` to recognise the run-time type of its input. If I could do something like

```
// In class Evaualor. Maybe (Out) is a parameter the class, not the method.
Out evaluate(Out)(Expr e) {
    if (isType!Num(e)) {
        return evalNum(cast(Num) e);
    }
    else if (isType!Str(e)) {
        return evalStr(cast(Str) e);
    }
    else if (isType!List(e)) {
        return evalList(cast(List) e);
    }
    and so on
}
```

then the `Expr` would need to know nothing about the `Evaluator` or the type that its `evaluate` method emits.

Is there such a way to determine the actual run-time type of such variables? That would save me some time.

Comment: Another option is to make `Expr` a `struct` (instead of a class) and add an
`ExprType type` field, where
`ExprType` is an enum of `Number`, `String`, `List`, etc. The expression 
type can be
checked, and the right evaluator function dispatched, at runtime (in my code,
instead of in the compiler's code at compile-time), and because `struct Expr`
can not be sub-classed anyway, the `final` nature of templatised methods is
moot, and not an issue.